# select multiple files in CFileDialog

Tags: mfc

In VC++ 6.0, MFC I want to select a multiple files

```
CFileDialog opendialog(true); // opens the dialog for open;
opendialog.m_ofn.lpstrTitle="SELECT FILE"; //selects the file title;
opendialog.m_ofn.lpstrFilter="text files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0"; //selects the filter;

if(opendialog.DoModal()==IDOK) //checks wether ok or cancel button is pressed;
{
    srcfilename=opendialog.GetPathName(); //gets the path name;
    ...
}
```

The code sample above allows only a single file being selected at a time, but I want to select multiple text files, for example by holding down control key (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+select the multiple files). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

So in the constructor for CFileDialog you can set the dwFlags parameter to have 'OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT'. Thats the easy part, to actually get the multiple file names back you have to modify the m_ofn.lpstrFile member in the CFileDialog to point to a buffer that you have allocated. Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d(VS.80).aspx

Here is an example use of it, hope the comments suffice:

```
void CMainFrame::OnFileOpen()
{
    char strFilter[] = { "Rule Profile (*.txt)|*.txt*||" };

    CFileDialog FileDlg(TRUE, "txt", NULL, OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, strFilter);
    CString str;
    int nMaxFiles = 256;
    int nBufferSz = nMaxFiles*256 + 1;
    FileDlg.GetOFN().lpstrFile = str.GetBuffer(nBufferSz);
    if( FileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK )
    {
        // The resulting string should contain first the file path:
        int pos = str.Find(' ', 0);
        if ( pos == -1 );
            //error here
        CString FilePath = str.Left(pos);
        // Each file name is seperated by a space (old style dialog), by a NULL character (explorer dialog)
        while ( (pos = str.Find(' ', pos)) != -1 )
        {   // Do stuff with strings
        }
    }
    else
        return; 
}
```

Comment: still i am confusion , i am not getting clearly, please will u give me sample of code or any example,or please modify my code given above thank you

Comment: don't you need to call str.ReleaseBuffer() after DoModal()?

Comment: @Magnus: I agree! Should also do `FileDlg.GetOFN().nMaxFiles = nMaxFiles` before `DoModal`.

Answer (score 7):

An example:

```
CString sFilter = _T("XXX Files (*.xxx)|*.xxx|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");


CFileDialog my_file_dialog(TRUE, _T("xxx"),NULL,
                           OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT,
                           sFilter, this);

if ( my_file_dialog.DoModal()!=IDOK )
    return;

POSITION pos ( my_file_dialog.GetStartPosition() );
while( pos )
{
    CString filename= my_file_dialog.GetNextPathName(pos);

    //do something with the filename variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag in [OpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839(VS.85).aspx) structure to allow the multi selection.

Comment: please can you me a example  so that i will get more clear ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line:

```
opendialog.m_ofn.Flags |= OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT;
```

Or set the flag in the CFileDialog constructor as DeusAduro did.

Answer (score 0):

None of the supplied answers are complete. Some are wrong in terms of parameters.

Here's an example of multi-file selection and open:

```
// an approximate arbitrary file limit of 200
uint32_t maxOpenFiles = 200;    

// A buffer to hold 200 file paths (using the old 260 char path limit). Going to assume its allocated.
TCHAR* lpszFiles = new TCHAR[maxOpenFiles * MAX_PATH]; // MAX_PATH is 260 here
lpszFiles[0] = 0; // don't forget this!

CFileDialog dlgOpen(TRUE, L"*", NULL, OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, L"All Files (*.*)|*.*||");

dlgOpen.m_ofn.lpstrFile = lpszFiles;
dlgOpen.m_ofn.nMaxFile = maxOpenFiles * MAX_PATH;   // not the file count, but the size of the buffer in characters.

if (dlgOpen.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString sFilePath;

    POSITION pos = dlgOpen.GetStartPosition();

    while (pos)
    {
        // fetch each file path
        sFilePath = dlgOpen.GetNextPathName(pos);

        // do something with the file path
        // OpenMe(sFilePath);
    }
}

// free the path buffer (assuming it was allocated)
delete[] lpszFiles;
```